# WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes class not returning data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Using the Woocommerce API, I'm calling classes and showing fetched data through this syntax:

```
$data= new class( id );
print_r($data);
```

Everything is showing as expected except for this one:

```
WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes()
```

I'm calling it through this syntax:

```
$notes = new WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes( $order_id);
print_r($notes);
```

But it just shows as empty:

```
WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes Object ( )
```

What am I missing?[image]

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Looking at the [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.14/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-notes.php) it only has a static class for outputting the metabox. It doesn't have any class properties.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic what we see on the Edit Order page and show it on frontend (with limited access).

Comment: What if you just call the output method? `WC_Meta_Box_Order_Notes::output( $post )` where `$post` is the post object for the order in question.